# python - is it possible to split up a gzip api response file into less GB

Tags: python, json, api, gzip

Hi guys i am able to pull data from the an api response but the file is too big more than 4 GB so i want to ask if there is a way to split the data from gzip file into smaller chunks?

I tried using a curl command I see data  downloading  and working perfectly fine 
then I try using this same curl logic into the python

```
curl -H "X-Risk-Token: $token" "https://api.nyc3.us.thisismyurl.com/vulnerabilities/download_data_zip" -o file.gz -vv
```

here is my python code:

```
import requests
import  gzip
import json
import csv


# url ='https://api.thisismyurl.com/vulnerabilities/download_data_zip'
token = 'blahblahblah'
# 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
headers = {'X-Risk-Token': token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
json_format = json.loads(response.text)
print(json_format)
```

here is my output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPoc5.png)
Can you show an example of this?

Thanks

Comment: too big for what?  the unix utility `split` works for dividing a file up, `cat` is fine for putting everything back together

Comment: I assume you wrote python code to fetch a response from the server.

It's best you show your code and tell us what the code does and what changes you try to implement.

What do you want to do with the response?
display it?

Write it to a file?

Write it to a gzip file?

Write it to multiple files with a max size of x?

Write it to a list of gzip files where the size is approximately x?

Comment: you could use `requests` in streaming mode and create a writer class, that chunks your output.

But before sending any answer I'd like to be sure what you're really asking for.

Comment: @gelonida I have edited my question and i want to display it to see for myself and then ultimately write it to file later on but since there is a quota(4GB) of how much I can download,the file obviously exceeds the quota which leds me here to my question

Comment: why do you only accept 'application/json' I don't see, that you specify this in your curl command.

Where exactly is the quota?

Comment: @gelonida Curl will infer a content-type normally. Since this is a gzip file that is being exported, my code can either specify this manually or leave out the content-type and the requests library should infer that header automatically.  and the quota is google cloud function limit sorry for the delayed response

Comment: could you please comment on my suggested answer?
What's the output (please copy and paste as text) does this what you want. If not what should be different?

And in general for better debugging and understanding best to explicily add the same headers to curl and to the python code.

Is there any way for you to create a temporary restricted token, so that we I can try curl vs python.
This what helped me find the solution to another question.
If we can't reproduce it's more cumbersome.

Comment: concerning the google cloud limit:
you are executing the curl command and the python script on the same machine? curl doesn't hit the quota, but the python script does?

Comment: @gelonida im assuming both because I run the python & curl  and i still get this chunking error in the snapshot above

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly the same thing that you did with curl you had to do following:

```
import requests
import shutil

# curl -H "X-Risk-Token: $token" "https://api.nyc3.us.thisismyurl.com/vulnerabilities/download_data_zip" -o file.gz -vv

url ='https://api.thisismyurl.com/vulnerabilities/download_data_zip'
token = 'blahblahblah'
fname = "file.gz"
# 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
headers = {'X-Risk-Token': token } # exactly same header as curl.

# memory friendly way to download big files
with requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True) as resp:
    print(res.status_code)
    with open(fname, 'wb') as fout:
        shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, fout)
```

json.loads() of your original code will consume a lot of RAM and might make your process crash if you don't have enough RAM available.

What exactly would you like to do with the data?

visualizing the data could be done with:

```
import gzip
import shutil
with gzip.open(fname) as fin:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fin, sys.stdout)
```

As there is still no success I suggest and I did not get any information, that explains why the 'quota' causes issues for the python script, but not for curl I suggest some more tests.

1.) download but don't store the result (is it the network which is blocked / aborting??)

```
url ='https://api.thisismyurl.com/vulnerabilities/download_data_zip'
token = 'blahblahblah'
headers = {'X-Risk-Token': token } # exactly same header as curl.

# memory friendly way to download big files
with requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True) as resp:
    print(res.status_code)
    downloaded = 0
    try:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            downloaded += len(chunk)
    except Exception:
        print("Downloaded %d bytes and got an exception" % downloaded)
        raise
print("Downloaded %d bytes" % downloaded)
```

Please check whether the result is always the same or whether the number you get varies

Comment: I tried your code and I got this huge beast https://imgur.com/c1sjbL3 haha and reading it it cuts off at a certain point because the files is just too huge specifically 2.97

Comment: and when I run the script multiple times it changes the size of the file 3.82, 1.82, etc and this error occurs https://imgur.com/EeylQG9

Comment: ultimately what I want to do with the data is to be able to see everything inside of the data then cherry pick which fields i want

Comment: It's still unclear to me why  suggested py and  curl  on the same machine behave differently?

What's important for the right solution is to understand exactly who complains and why. Is it the amount of bytes being transferredor the amount of bytes written to disk?

can you type `df -h` in a console? could it be, that python script and curl write to different partitions? or do you write into the same directory?

Whatever: A solution should be to `gunzip` the stream and use `ijson` to parse. 

Will have time again in a few hours

Comment: Please post the exact output of your curl command with the `-vv` option in your question as a reference.
Obviously you can replace all tokens or confidential stuff with xxx, but it is important to see  the entire output . something might explain the issue.

Please confirm also __explicitely__ that you execute the curl command on the same machine in the same directory as the same user than the python command. Or if this is not the case do so.

Comment: please try the code snippet in my answer that will show you how many bytes you downloaded and check whether the result  is predicatable or varies every time you call your script.